# Is Eevee ignoring motion blur on particles?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have enabled motion blur on Eevee.
It works fine, but it seems that it is ignoring particles (and also meshes moving along a curve modifier).

By any chance, is there a way to make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: Read: [Blender Cycles vs. Eevee - 15 Limitations of Real Time Rendering in Blender 2.8](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/engines/eevee/motion_blur.html) the object motion blur (particles as well) is not yet supported. It probably will be but we have to wait to get all the features in Eevee.

The only way is to use cycles now.

Comment: Eevee supports only camera motion blur for now.